# Localization tool to find all UI strings

Tags: c#, visual-studio, localization, globalization

This is a bit of a reach, but i figured its worth a shot. I have been tasked with making a very large program localizable which initially was not written to support it. That means literal strings are everywhere throughout the 387 code files for the project.

Does anyone know of a tool which can generate a list of localizable strings that have the possibility to be displayed on the GUI? There is an error log with literal strings as well that is written to, and I do not want to translate those.

I know its a long shot!

Comment: What UI framework are you using?

Comment: sorry, should have specified. Winforms in VS2013. .NET 4

Comment: This question is a possible duplicate of [Find all source hardcoded strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490974/find-all-source-hardcoded-strings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/internationalization.html) provides tools to find localizable strings and more easily move them to resource files.

Comment: Thanks for the reply tooslow. Can ReSharper limit its find to strings that make their way to the UI? I tried ReSharper already to find all localizable strings, and it gave me close to 8000 results.

Comment: ReSharper has some pretty complex custom pattern support.  It should be possible to create a pattern that will detect your particular needs.

Comment: Cool, I'll mess around with it some more and post if i figure it out.