# Missing ReSharper category for csproj properties

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, localization, resharper-7.1

I want to do what is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490974/find-all-source-hardcoded-strings).

As stated [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/help/Localization_Inspection.html), there should be a category called "ReSharper" where I can set the `Localizable` option.
However, I can't find this option nor the category in my (web)projects properties.
I've already tried to add a new `resx` as file and via `Properties->Ressources`.

What's missing or what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer from the ReShaper Support-team:

They stated that this feature has been introduced with ReSharper 8. 
So the problem is my version 7 ReSharper.